# Removing an account/user from scope

Tags: crm, customer

I'm working on a CRM at the moment which allows an operator to search for a customer and verify them, after which the whole system is aimed to work on that customer's account.

I'm working on the UX for 'dropping' the customer from scope. So far on the customer overview there's a trash button and a confirm, what I'm looking for is a question for the verify.

So far I have "Stop viewing this customer?" and "Finished with this customer?" but I don't like them. I know this might be a little more of a copy writing question than UX, but any ideas better than mine?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple and give them an option as **Mark as viewed** or **Mark as completed.**

This allows the user to know that if he marks the customer as viewed, he has an option to filter them out the next time he searches.

This is very commonly used in a number of cases especially email and users can understand it fast

[image]

That said,some A/B testing might be helpful to understand what wordings work best

Answer (score 0):

Unless by 'dropping the customer' you mean removing them from the system as your customer, I would suggest not using a trash icon to indicate being done with working on that customers account. 'Trashing' an instance of something typically indicates that it will be deleted.
Some other options to consider would be:

- A back arrow with phrasing similar to "Choose Another Customer" or "Back to Customer List"
- A button that says "Finished with *Customer Name*"

You could either make the buttons only available on the overview page, or present on all pages with a confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the user within a bounded visual scope e.g. a box within the webpage (that has a small margin from the title, sides and footer) then you can add a standard "X" and close button to that scope and it should be clear that you are only closing that scope and not the entire app/page.

As the other answer mentioned, don't use a recycle bin to close a scope, users will think it its for deleting the context of the scope (the observed user) from the system.